# Is it possible to build a Netbeans Matisse based project without Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, gui-builder, matisse

Part of a project I'm on has a GUI app that is built with Netbeans using the GUI design tools that come in that IDE.

But this is only part of a bigger project, and needs to be built in an environment that does not have Netbeans installed (it happens to be a Gradle-based build on Jenkins).  I've gotten builds to (seemingly) work, but keep running into inexplicable run-time errors (i.e., dependencies appear to be met with identical jars on the classpath and so on, but attempts to read resources from the project jar fail.).

From googling around, it looks like this might have something to do with compiling .form files and then including some dependency for the resulting java. (though, the Netbeans build does not add any jars above what our gradle build adds).

So the question is... can this even be done? or does a proper build simply rely on some hidden build-time mojo that's going on in Netbeans?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can compile the classes without NetBeans. Just be sure you do not any NetBeans library, like `AbsoluteLayout`. The `.form` files are for NetBeans showing you components with Matisse, but all the generated code will be in the `.java` file.